# txtUML stateMachine diagram model of customer order food in restuarant

Tags: eclipse, txtuml

I am seeking help and advice to help me in this stateMachine model for allowing a customer to order food in a restaurant in xtxUml. I want to display a model like the in the image below, so how do I fix the codes below? I get a result without any association. I appreciate your advice and help.

```
class RestuarantClasses extends ClassDiagram {
    @Spacing(0.5)
    @TopMost(People.class)
    @Row({Customer.class, Worker.class})
    @Column({People.class, Worker.class,Waiter.class})
    @Row({Cooker.class, Waiter.class, Cashier.class})
}
class RestuarantLayout extends Layout {}
}



class CustomerStates extends StateMachineDiagram<Customer> {
    @TopMost({Customer.OpenDoor.class})
    @Row({Customer.Waiting.class, Customer.StartSelection.class})
    @Row({Customer.SaladOrNoodle.class, Customer.OrderSteak.class})
    @Row({Customer.OrderNoodle.class, Customer.OrderSalad.class})

class L extends Layout {
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the next layout constraints for nodes:

`@Above(val = A.class, from = B.class)` : Box A is north from B and is right next to it.`

`@Right(val = A.class, from = B.class)` : Box A is east from B and is right next to it.`

`@Below(val = A.class, from = B.class)` : Box A is south from B and is right next to it.`

`@Left(val = A.class, from = B.class)` : Box A is west from B and is right next to it.`

your code should look like:

```
@Above(val = OpenDoor.class, from = Waiting.class)
@Row({Waiting.class, StartSelection.class})
@Below(val= SaladOrNoodle.class, from = Waiting.class)
@Below(val=OrderNoodle.class, from = SaladOrNoodle.class)
@Right(val=OrderSalad.class, from = OrderNoodle.class)
@Right(val=OrderSteak.class, from = SaladOrNoodle.class)
@Below(val = Payment.class, from = OrderSalad.class)
```

Comment: Much appreciated your advice Diana Cristina

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some typo in your sample code. The `Layout` class should be an inner class of the Diagram like this:

```java
    class RestuarantClasses extends ClassDiagram {
        @Spacing(0.5)
        @TopMost(People.class)
        @Row({Customer.class, Worker.class})
        @Column({People.class, Worker.class,Waiter.class})
        @Row({Cooker.class, Waiter.class, Cashier.class})
        class RestuarantLayout extends Layout {}
    }
```

In the StateMachine description you must specify vertical relationship between the boxes as well. The algorithm cannot resolve the vertical allignment of your rows.

Otherwise I see no problem with your Diagram descriptions.

**Note1:** With `Above`, `Below`, `Left` and `Right` you can express direct neighbourship of boxes. Using `Row` and `Column` is a convenient form of expressing the same relations.

**Note2:** You didn't write the `Payment` state anywhere. Boxes that are not included in the Diagram Description won't be present on the diagram by default. If you want to say nothing about a box, but you want to see it use the `Show` annotation. 
[Read more about the diagram description language](http://txtuml.inf.elte.hu/wiki/doku.php?id=v050:layout)

---

It is very strage that you don't get any associations. Links between the boxes presented on the diagrams are automatically arranged and visualized.

I tried to recreate your model, it should work fine:

```
    package restaurant.model;

    class People;
    class Worker extends People;
    class Cooker extends Worker;
    class Cashier extends Worker;
    class Waiter extends Worker;

    class Customer extends People{
        initial OpenDoor;
        state Waiting;
        state StartSelection;
        state SaladOrNoodle;
        state OrderSteak;
        state OrderNoodle;
        state OrderSalad;
        state Payment;

        transition tr1{
            from OpenDoor;
            to Waiting;
        }

        transition startSelectionTr{
            from Waiting;
            to StartSelection;
            trigger StartSelectionSignal;
        }

        transition orderSteakTr{
            from StartSelection;
            to OrderSteak;
            trigger OrderSteakSignal;
        }

        transition orderSaladOrNoodleTr{
            from StartSelection;
            to SaladOrNoodle;
            trigger OrderSaladOrNoodleSignal;
        }

        transition orderSaladTr{
            from SaladOrNoodle;
            to OrderSalad;
            trigger OrderSaladSignal;
        }

        transition orderNoodleTr{
            from SaladOrNoodle;
            to OrderNoodle;
            trigger OrderNoodleSignal;
        }

        transition payTr1{
            from OrderNoodle;
            to Payment;
            trigger PaySignal;
        }

        transition payTr2{
            from OrderSteak;
            to Payment;
            trigger PaySignal;
        }

        transition payTr3{
            from SaladOrNoodle;
            to Payment;
            trigger PaySignal;
        }
    }

    signal StartSelectionSignal;
    signal OrderSteakSignal;
    signal OrderSaladOrNoodleSignal;
    signal OrderSaladSignal;
    signal OrderNoodleSignal;
    signal PaySignal;
```